# How to use relationships to extract data via select

Tags: select, sqlite

Disclaimer: Novice in SQL

I have 3 tables. There is one "major" table (labeled `used_for_lookup` below) used to do look-ups on and the other two (labeled `fid_table` and `did_table` below) are foreign keys in the major table. For the sake of the argument, the tables below have been simplified down to the problem.

The database operations insert into the `did_table` and `fid_table`. These are generally very infrequent. When an event occurs, the details are captured in the `used_for_lookup` table. This table is then used to do `SELECTS` on. The columns `fid` and `did` in the `used_for_lookup` table are references into the `fid_table` and `did_table`.

A simplified version with data:

```
sqlite> select * from used_for_lookup;
id          datetime    fid         did
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           2014-10-10  1           1
sqlite> select * from did_table;
id          other_ints  did_important_string
----------  ----------  -----------------------------------------------------
1           1           this needs to go into the query result from did table
sqlite> select * from fid_table;
id          other_ints  fid_important_string
----------  ----------  -----------------------------------------------------
1           1           this needs to go into the query result from fid table
```

The most general query is that we query `used_for_lookup` table between 2 date events on the datatime column.

When we do a select, like so:

```
sqlite> select * from used_for_lookup where datetime between '2014-10-09' and '2014-10-11';
id          datetime    fid         did
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           2014-10-10  1           1
```

we need to "convert" `fid` and `did` column values to the `fid_important_string` and `did_important_string` values for when we report back the answer.

They are foreign keys which helps with data integrity, but I'm stumped on how do you now use the column lookups to get the strings out of other tables into one answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select used_for_lookup.id,
        used_for_lookup.datetime,
        fid_table.fid_important_string,
        did_table.did_important_string
 from used_for_lookup 
 join fid_table on fid_table.id = used_for_lookup.fid
 join did_table on did_table.id = used_for_lookup.did
where datetime between '2014-10-09' and '2014-10-11';
```

Comment: Thanks - that works 99% correctly. For some reason on SQLite it need to add `left join` rather than just `join` otherwise 0 rows are returned. `left join` outputs the expected version so accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL performs the join you need.

```
select 
     used_for_lookp.id
    ,used_for_lookup.datetime
    ,fid_table.fid_important_string
    ,did_table.did_important_string
from used_for_lookup
join fid_table on fid_table.id = used_for_lookup.fid
join did_table on did_table.id = used_for_lookup.did
```

Comment: `datetime` is not an [SQLite keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).